# jQuery enable form if checked checkboxes into array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to enable form if checkboxes that are currently checked and store them into an array.

Here is my form code so far:

```
<?php $index = 0; ?>
@foreach($dayOfWeek as $key => $day )
<div class="parttime">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::text('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][day]',$day, ['class' => 'form-control','disabled'])!!}
                {!! Form::hidden('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][day]',$key, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
                {!! Form::hidden('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][id]',null) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::text('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][start_time]', null, ['class' => 'form-control start_time','placeholder' => 'Start time', 'disabled'])!!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::text('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][end_time]', null, ['class' => 'form-control end_time','placeholder' => 'End time', 'disabled'])!!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::text('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][hours]', null, ['id' => 'hours','class' => 'form-control','readonly'])!!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::checkbox('parttimeAvailabilities['.$index.'][available]')!!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $index++; ?>
@endforeach
```

and here's my jQuery code so far :

```
$('div.parttime').each(function(index) {
        var checkbox = $('input[name="parttimeAvailabilities['+index+'][available]"]');
        var startbox = $('select[name="parttimeAvailabilities['+index+'][start_time]"]');
        var endbox = $('select[name="parttimeAvailabilities['+index+'][end_time]"]');
        $(startbox).prop("enable", $(checkbox).prop('checked'));
        $(endbox).prop("enable", $(checkbox).prop('checked'));

        $('#driverForm').bootstrapValidator('addField', startbox, {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The start time is required and cannot be empty'
                },
            }
        });
        $('#driverForm').bootstrapValidator('addField', endbox, {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The end time is required and cannot be empty'
                },
            }
        });
        $(checkbox).on('click', function(e) {
            $(selectbox).select2('val', '');
            var bootstrapValidator = $('#driverForm').data('bootstrapValidator');
            bootstrapValidator.enableFieldValidators(startbox, !$(checkbox).prop('checked'));
            bootstrapValidator.enableFieldValidators(endbox, !$(checkbox).prop('checked'));
            $(startbox).prop("enable", $(checkbox).prop('checked'));
            $(endbox).prop("enable", $(checkbox).prop('checked'));
        });
    });
```

it throws this error :

> bootstrapValidator.js:1521 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'validators' of undefined

any idea ??

Comment: i don't see any `#driverForm`. Ofc you got an error, just because you try to call validator on the undefined div

Comment: I've put that in the top of my code.

Comment: @extends('layout.master')
@section('content')
{!! Form::model($obj, [
    'url' => $route,
    'method' => $method,
    'id' => 'driverForm',
]) !!}